# Why isn't XLoadQueryFont recognising name 8x13

Tags: c, xorg

I call the function `XLoadQueryFont(port->dpy, "8x13")`, but it returns a NULL. I'm pretty sure I had this working before. If I type `locate 8x13`, one of the results is

```
/usr/share/fonts/misc/8x13.pcf.gz
```

I don't know what the function dislikes, and was wondering as to how to track the problem down.

**Update**:

Using "fixed" produced an app that executed.

Based on tofo's comments:

I had to install the xlsfonts binary on Arch to get `xlsfonts`. It listed adobe, lucida, bitstream and misc fonts. `xlsfonts | grep misc` returned

```
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--0-0-75-75-c-0-iso8859-1 
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-100-100-100-c-60-iso8‌​859-1 
-misc-fixed-medium-r-semicondensed--13-120-75-75-c-60-iso885‌​9-1
```

Comment: does `xlsfonts` list the font? Otherwise the server's font path might be screwed up.

Comment: @tofro I updated the question regarding xlsfonts.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have deleted or corrupted your `fonts.alias` file in /etc/X11 (or similar location, depending on your distribution, can be anywhere in the font path).

The "8x13" is typically no name, but rather an alias that is defined in this file.

To ensure your server can use this font name, check that your fonts.alias file contains at least the lines (note your actual font names might vary)

```
8x13     -Misc-Fixed-Medium-R-SemiExpanded--13-120-75-75-C-80-ISO8859-1
8x13bold -Misc-Fixed-Bold-R-SemiExpanded--13-120-75-75-C-80-ISO8859-1
```

If those aliases are not present or don't resolve to a valid font, you cannot use the "8x13" name. More aliases can be defined as needed.